# Incorporating Python inside a Flask HTML page

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, flask

Let's say I have a flask_app.py application  which contains some HTML code, and I want to print a python variable :

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

myString = foo

@app.route("/")
def hello():
  return """<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <body>
                <p>""" + myString + """
            </body>
        </html>"""
```

Now this works fine, but isn't really extendable. I have the basic HTML snippet in an `index.html` file, how can I produce the same result using it (and printing `myString` ) ?

Comment: IIUC you want something similar to an erb file with RoR, right? have you looked at jinja2?

Comment: The answer to your question is in the flask doc. It is specifically in [the section that introduces templates](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#rendering-templates).

Comment: @SrinivasSuresh Yes something similar to that. I will take a look at jinja2 if it allows passing python variables inside html.

Comment: @stamaimer and Rob are correct. The flask docs talk specifically about stuff ike this and even they point you to the jinja2 docs, so do read them

Comment: @Robᵩ Yes perfect! Just started Flask today, I should've read first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this file is in `/tmp/x.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

myString = 'foo'

@app.route("/")
def hello():
  return render_template('index.html', myString=myString)

app.run(debug=True)
```

and this file in `/tmp/templates/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>{{ myString }}
    </body>
</html>
```

then run this command:

```
python /tmp/x.py
```

Reference:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#rendering-templates